# Serve ionic app to remote systems

Tags: ubuntu, firewall, iptables, ionic3

I have started new ionic app on cloud 
OS : Ubuntu
I serve my app using ionic serve --address 0.0.0.0 --port 8100
But still I am not able to access from ip http://103.50.0.161:8100/

So please kindly help me to solve my issue

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry Finally i found the answer
-A INPUT -j REJECT --reject-with icmp-port-unreachable 
just delete this rule from iptables